# Android - Edittext soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-softkeyboard

I've a `ListView` with an `EditText` ; when I touch the `EditText`, the soft keyboard will appear and I've entered some text, it's fine. But after entering the text, press backspace button (not back button) and the activity will finish.

Why does it happen ? What went wrong here? How can i solve this?
Please someone help me to find out this riddle.

In xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minLines="15"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        />
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/notes_to_parents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In java.
This for loop is inside of Listview onScroll Action.

```
for (int i = 0; i < daily_dairy_2.getChildCount(); i++) 
                {
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) daily_dairy_2.getChildAt(i);
final EditText notes_to     = (EditText) layout.getChildAt(0);

}
```

I know here i don't write any code for edittext. How to hanle this edittext.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: No crash so nothing in logcat.

Comment: Put your code so we can identify problem..

Comment: here I use Listview and load this layout using simpleadapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set OnKeyListener for you editText so you can detect any key press

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
             if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
                 //this is for backspace
                 }
        return false;       
            }
    });
```

this is code handle backspace Button

Answer (score 0):

Make your own implementation for the press of backspace.

It's something like this

```
public final static int CodeDelete   = -5;
public class MyKeyboard extends InputMethodService
implements OnKeyboardActionListener{
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {    
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
 switch(primaryCode){
    case CodeDelete :
        ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        break;
```

and in your keyboard's xml:

```
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete_dim">
```